# How to Count form in a div using Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, html, cout

I have a some problem with count form in a `div`.

I want to count forms element in a `div`. But i am not how to do.

Thank everyone

Comment: Share the jsFiddle of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
var top_level_div = document.getElementById('id_of_first_div');
var count = top_level_div.getElementsByTagName('form').length;
```